# Sólo obtengo un resultado en la consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Estaba probando conseguir los datos de una tabla, pero solo consigo que salga un dato.
Lo hice fijándome en un ejemplo, pero no sé que fallo hay la verdad

```
public function listarUsuarios(){

                $sql = "SELECT *FROM usuario  ";
                $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                        $row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                        return $row;
                    }

                    $this->conn->close();
            }

             <?php

    foreach ($row as $key){

            echo $key['nia'].'<br';
            echo $key['password'].'<br';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes que cerrar las etiquetas `<br>` , quedaria de las siguiente manera:

```
 echo $key['nia'].'<br>';
 echo $key['password'].'<br>';
```